# High route time in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have 5 modules in my `zf2` application ,
i used

> 'config_cache_key' => 'module_config_cache'

and cache enabled and work ok

but the  problem is `zenddevelopertools` show route time between 1 second  and 2 second

i cheked for regex checking in my routes, but my routers doesnt use regex and only use hostname for routing

why my routing time is too high ?

Comment: Do you have a lot of listeners based on EVENT_ROUTE ?

Comment: @Hooli no i have not any listeners on EVENT_ROUTE